# Showing svg file in html

Tags: html, svg

I am trying to show an svg in html.
It is important that the svg file is a file and not just in the html code. The file looks as following:

```
<svg height="100" width="100">
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
   ...
</svg>
```

The svg file works in firefox when I open it but I cannot implement it in my html code. Can someone help?

Comment: `<img src="pathtoyourimage.svg">`

Comment: Because you're missing the [SVG namespace declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course) perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

My index.html file has:

```
# html code ...

<svg xmls="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <img src="/static/lstring.svg">
</svg>

# html code ...
```

And still doesn't work